# Duplicate or create same shape Word using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm trying to create to create VBA code that allows me to create or duplicate the same shape that is already existant in word and put it on the same position 
For Now my codes can only move shapes from X or Y to another postion in word  but I want is to duplicate that shape , I made some researches and what I found is this Code

```
Set dChart = Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1).Duplicate 
dChart.Select
```

I don't know how to adapt it to duplicate or to create the same shape 
Name of the shape "Groupe 391"

Comment: @Siddharth Rout

Comment: remove the excel-vba tag if you are not using excel.

Comment: It's excel  VBA  and word  I make all the controls from a macro inn excel  which allow me to modify word

Comment: replace (1) with ("Gropue 391")

Comment: and name chart doesn't cause a problem it's same like shape ?

Comment: Well your worksheet part should reference your word file, same as you would do with moving a shape.

Comment: So you want to duplicate a shape in Word from Excel? If yes, then try this `objWordDoc.Shapes("Groupe 391").Duplicate`

Comment: i succeed with the duplication but How can I change the text inside that shape

Comment: If frame.Value = "2" Then
    wrdDoc.Shapes("Groupe 643").Duplicate
    wrdDoc.Shapes("Groupe 643").Name = " Groupe 644"
    
     Set shp = wrdDoc.Shapes("Groupe 643")

    With shp
        .Left = Sheets("Feuil1").Range("J3")
    End With
    wrdDoc.Shapes("Groupe 644").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "FME1"